# How to you configure Selenium Webdriver to take in command line options with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, command-line

I have the following resources, but I'm not sure how to interpret them for this particular goal ([this](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html) and [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities)). I'm using Selenium WebDriver through Node.js, and so far, all my tests work as I wish, but now I wish to add command line options to it to make it more dynamic. As it stands now, my test file is called mytests.js. To start these tests, I simply run the following command in the terminal.

```
node mytests.js
```

This starts all my 100+ tests. The problem is that these all take quite a while to complete. Maybe 45 minutes to 1.5 hours. I'd like to add the options to choose which test, or set of tests to actually run, based on input from the command line. So my goal is to have something like this:

```
node mytests.js targetName
```

So, in mind, 'targetName' would be just be to focus on and apply tests related to the given target/url. This is just an example. The start of my test file appears like such:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var path = require('chromedriver').path;

var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
chrome.setDefaultService(service);

var driver = new webdriver.Builder() 
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.manage().logs().get('browser');

// . . .
```

What can I add to these to make it possible to add in command line options? Can someone please provide an example in JavaScript instead of only links to other pages?

Comment: You should investigate the equivalent to JUnit, NUnit, TestNG, etc. for Node.js. I'm sure one exists and that should help you figure out how to do this. For these others, there is an XML file where you specify what gets run and other settings.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine directed me to the [process.argv](https://code-maven.com/argv-raw-command-line-arguments-in-nodejs) variable. It gave me exactly what I needed to solve this problem. :)

So, adding the following to mytest.js:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

Will echo the follow to the console.

```
$ node mytests.js this is a command
[ 'mytests.js',
  'this',
  'is',
  'a',
  'command' ]
```